# \ifnum and pgfmath: error

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, pgfmath

In the following example I want to use \ifnum to compare two numbers computed by pgfmath, for simplicity I use simply 1 and 2 in the example below. Compiling this code gives me the error:

```
    ERROR: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   .
l.11    \ifnum \one
                   <\two
--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.
```

The example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\one}{1};
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\two}{2};
   \ifnum \one<\two
   \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
   \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`\ifnum` compares integers. The results stored by `\pgfmathsetmacro` always contain a decimal part, even for integer numbers, so you'll have to use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\one{1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\two{2}
   \ifnum\one<\two
   \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
   \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Warnings: not to be used when FPU is enabled and the output format is float, will silently return wrong result. Refer to [tikz pgf - pgfplots and calculations; without fpu 'dimension too large', with fpu 'Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)' - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/pgfplots-and-calculations-without-fpu-dimension-too-large-with-fpu-illegal?noredirect=1&lq=1)