# pgfplots and calculations; without fpu 'dimension too large', with fpu 'Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)'

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

I'm trying to multiply some numbers that will end up in the legend of a plot. I can't get it to work:

1. If I naively try `\pgfmathmultiply`, I get a `dimension too large` error, with the code in **MWE 1** (see below). I understand this is because TeX doesn't count beyond 18 inch (or so). All right, I need to load `fpu`, as explained in section 36 of the `pgfmanual` (version 2.10).
2. If I pass `/pgf/fpu` to an axis-environment, compilation fails with `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` (with **MWE 2**). Even if the axis-environment is completely empty. According to " [How do I use pgfmathdeclarefunction to create define a new pgf function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-do-i-use-pgfmathdeclarefunction-to-create-define-a-new-pgf-function)", `pgfplots` uses `fpu` internally, so I don't really understand why I can't load it.
3. Maybe I'm using a wrong function, I thought. On page 362 of the PGF-manual, I read *The installation exchanges any routines of the standard math parser with those of the FPU: `\pgfmathadd` will be replaced with `\pgfmathfloatadd` and so on. Furthermore, any number will be parsed with `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber`*. So, if I already have the FPU, maybe I need to use `\pgfmathfloatmultiply` instead? I tried with **MWE 3**, but this time it fails to compile with: *! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number '1000'. The unreadable part was near '1000'..*. Maybe `\pgfmathmultiply` is not meant to be used by the user, or so.

How do I multiply large numbers and show the result in my `pgfplot`?

Related yet different questions:

- [How do I use pgfmathdeclarefunction to create define a new pgf function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-do-i-use-pgfmathdeclarefunction-to-create-define-a-new-pgf-function)
- [How can I avoid the "Dimension too large" error when plotting in newer PGF versions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33082/how-can-i-avoid-the-dimension-too-large-error-when-plotting-in-newer-pgf-versi)
- [Dimension too large while plotting with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13816/dimension-too-large-while-plotting-with-pgfplots)

**MWE 1:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={\pgfmathmultiply{1000}{1000}}
          ]
\addplot coordinates {(0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**MWE 2**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[/pgf/fpu,
    title={\pgfmathmultiply{1000}{1000}}
          ]
\addplot coordinates {(0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**MWE 3**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={\pgfmathfloatmultiply{1000}{1000}}
          ]
\addplot coordinates {(0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PGFplots uses the `fpu` library internally, but not for everything. At the user level, the `fpu` library is not activated. You can do that by hand by setting `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}` before you do your maths using the normal `\pgfmathparse{...}` command. After you're done, you need to switch the `fpu` library back off again, otherwise PGFplots will get confused, since the `fpu` library uses a floating point representation of numbers, not a fixed point one. You can see what that looks like by saying

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfmathparse{1000*1000}
\pgfmathresult
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
```

which will print `1Y1.0e6]`. You probably don't want that representation in your title, so you should either set `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}`, which will make the output of maths operations fixed point, or use `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` for printing the result, which will use a fixed point representation even for floating point input.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{1000*1000}
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}}
          ]
\addplot coordinates {(0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just curious: could I have figured this out from the documentation? I did not consider that it would get confused.

Comment: @gerrit I took your question as encouragement to improve the manual. The reference manual entry for `\pgfmathparse` in pgfplots now contains at least some hints and an example.

Comment: Remark, if the `fpu` TikZ library is not loaded at all, the line `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}` might throw an error, refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496750/how-to-make-a-tikz-picture-coexist-with-the-fpu-library#comment1254186_496755.