# Questions about pgfmath

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu} 

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\x{5^2}
\show\x -> 25.0pt % OK, thanks.

\pgfmathparse{5cm^2}
```

1. What is the meaning of `]` in the following?

   ```
   \show\pgfmathresult % ->1Y2.0238983e4].

   \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
   ```

   gives the expected format, but what is the cryptic `]`?
2. Why does this fail? Is unit not allowed in `{<expr>}`? The manual says `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` "defines `<macro>` as the value of `<expression>` in points."

   ```
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\y{5cm^2} % ! Illegal unit.
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\y{5^2cm} % ! Illegal unit.
   \show\y
   ```

**EDIT**

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
\pgfmathparse{5cm^2}
%\show\pgfmathresult % -> 2.0238983e4.

% Both of these give error:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\x{5mm^2}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\x{5^2}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}

\end{document}

Error msg:

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                   e
l.10 \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\x{5mm^2}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a MWE help? *You* know which packages you're loading, we don't. I get an error from the first `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` call.

Comment: This is related to the internal number represantation of the `fpu` library and I think `]` is doing something similar to `\relax`. You have to use `\pgfmathprintnumber` to convert it to the human-readable form.

Comment: I get `! Dimension too large.` for both of the examples in part 2, probably because `5 cm` comes out 'too big' in `pt`.

Comment: Related question on the topic of FPU internal representation: [tikz pgf - pgfplots and calculations; without fpu 'dimension too large', with fpu 'Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)' - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/pgfplots-and-calculations-without-fpu-dimension-too-large-with-fpu-illegal)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `1Y2.0238983e4]` is the internal representation of the number. With `fpu` you have to explicitly specify the output format or use `\pgfmathfloattofixed`.
The default format is `float` (with `Y` and `]`), `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` is not changed by the `fpu` library, thus the length is not a valid TeX length with format `float`.
Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}

\begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\x{5^2}
  \typeout{\x}
\endgroup

\begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
  \pgfmathparse{5^2}
  \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}
  \edef\x{\pgfmathresult pt}
  \typeout{\x}
\endgroup

\begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
  \pgfmathparse{5cm^2}
  \typeout{\pgfmathresult}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
25.0pt
25.000000000pt
20238.983000000000
```

More details in [36 Floating Point Unit Library](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=362).