# `Missing = inserted for \ifnum` when using addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

I'm trying to plot a [normalized sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) with PGFPlots/TikZ. As this is somewhat tricky because of the limiting value at 0, I used a [suggestion provided by percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235009).

Here's a minimal example (note that I've renamed the function to `sincf` due to conflicts with the rest of the document and inserted an approximation of Pi to normalize):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235009
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{sincf}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)<0.01 ? int(1) : int(0)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0 %
            \pgfmathparse{1}%
        \else%
            \pgfmathparse{sin(3.14159*#1 r)/(3.14159*#1)}%
        \fi%
}

    \begin{axis}
        \addplot {sincf(\x)};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I'm getting two errors which I can't figure out:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
Y
l.23 \addplot plot (\x,{sincf(\x)});
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
Y
l.23 \addplot plot (\x,{sincf(\x)});
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Using MikTeX 2.9

Comment: The first cycle has `\pgfmathresult=0Y0.0e0]`, so not a good value for `\ifnum`.

Comment: Related question on the topic of FPU internal representation: [tikz pgf - pgfplots and calculations; without fpu 'dimension too large', with fpu 'Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)' - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/pgfplots-and-calculations-without-fpu-dimension-too-large-with-fpu-illegal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pgfplots` uses library `fpu` for better precision by default, which has a different internal number format. Therefore `\pgfresult` is not `1` or `0` anymore and `\ifnum` cannot be used.

```
\tikzset{fpu}
\pgfmathparse{int(0)}\show\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{int(1)}\show\pgfmathresult
```

The lines show `0Y0` for zero and `1Y1` for one.

In this case, the whole math can be put in one `\pgfmathparse` expression:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235009
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{sincf}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(abs(#1)<0.01) ? 1 : sin(pi*#1 r)/(pi*#1)}%
    }

    \begin{axis}
        \addplot {sincf(\x)};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Short, but very detailed, precise and quick answer. Thanks a lot! So if I get it right, `0Y0` is an internal representation of `fpu` which can't be used with `\ifnum`. But then why did the code by percusse work? Is it because `\draw plot` doesn't use `fpu` in contrast to `\addplot`?

Comment: @user2009388 Exactly.

Comment: Interesting. But then what does it use?

Comment: @user2009388 The default mathematical engine, unless a different is set explicitly, examples: library `fpu` with changed internal format, library `fixedpointarithmetic`, based on package `fp`, ...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, both of the existing answers have drawbacks.

[Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262538/250119): it exactly undoes the fix in the linked question. In this case `\addplot` just happens to not evaluate the function at `x=0`, but if it does...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{sincf}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(abs(#1)<0.01) ? 1 : sin(pi*#1 r)/(pi*#1)}%
    }
    \pgfmathparse{sincf(0)}

\end{document}
```

you got an error.

[Cryptc's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277759/250119) works, but only if the FPU is currently enabled and the output format is float.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfmathparse{1}  % stores 1.0000000000 to \pgfmathresult
\pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}  % \pgfmathfloattofixed, as with other \pgfmathfloat... functions, expect input in low-level PGF FPU representation

\end{document}
```

Error.

---

One way I can find to convert anything to an int is to round-trip through PGF's FPU:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% don't need fpu library!
\begin{document}

% works with both internal representation and "normal" representation

\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{1Y1.0e6]}
\pgfmathfloattoint\pgfmathresult
% now \pgfmathresult is always an integer

\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{1000000}
\pgfmathfloattoint\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

You can try `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`, but **this will silently
return the wrong error if the FPU is enabled and output format is float!**

---

So for this problem, the fix is

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{sinc}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)<0.01 ? 1 : 0}%
    % ======== add these 2 lines ========
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloattoint\pgfmathresult
    % ======== end ========
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0 %
        \pgfmathparse{1}%
    \else%
        \pgfmathparse{sin(3.14159*#1 r)/(3.14159*#1)}%
    \fi%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot {sinc(\x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% ======== double check it works with normal \draw plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[domain=0:0.5, samples=250] plot (\x,{sinc(20*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

works both with TikZ `\draw plot` and `\addplot`.

---

Alternatively, staying completely within the FPU, there's `\pgfmathfloatifflags`:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{sinc}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)<0.01}%
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}{1}{% "less than" is true
        \pgfmathparse{1}%
    }{% "less than" is false
        \pgfmathparse{sin(3.14159*#1 r)/(3.14159*#1)}%
    }%
}
```

Also a bit faster.

---

Another alternative, although specific to this question, is

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{sinc}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{(#1==0 ? 1: sin(3.14159*#1 r))/(#1==0 ? 1: 3.14159*#1)}%
}
```

(just stare at the code for a while you'll see why it works.)

---

I tried to make `ifthenelse` short-circuits, but evaluate-immediately-while-parsing behavior is quite hard-wired into the behavior of `\pgfmathparse`, so it seems difficult to fix.

Comment: Alternative to `\pgfmathfloattoint` includes `\pgfmathfloatvalueof` (returns a float, is expandable), `\pgfmathfloattosci` (as the name implies, stores result into `\pgfmathresult`). The input to all of them must be low-level FPU representation.

Comment: Trying other workarounds (e.g. parse as strings) doesn't work either. By default `\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(1<2, "1+1", "3")}` is already an error with FPU.

Comment: Related [Why does pgfmaths's ifthenelse evaluate both expressions? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279554/why-does-pgfmathss-ifthenelse-evaluate-both-expressions?noredirect=1&lq=1) ■ [pgfmath - Prevent expression evaluation for some values in TikZ - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220916/prevent-expression-evaluation-for-some-values-in-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Using a related [answer about **fpu** formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74925/90942), I was able to use `\ifnum` in the case that my result was within the [range of an int()](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54703/90942) [−16383.9998, +16383.9998].  The trick is to use `\pgfmathfloattofixed` on the `\pgfmathresult`.

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfmathparse{...do floating point math here (with an int() result)...}
\pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult} % this allows the conversion with int()
\edef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
\pgfmathsetmacro\iTmp{int(\tmp)} % convert with int()

\ifnum \iTmp>0
  ... do stuff ...
\fi
```