# \pgfmathdeclarefunction and LuaLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, luatex

Is it possible to use LuaLaTeX in `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`?

I tried with `sinh` which seems to work in `pgfmathsetmacro` but not in `\pgfmathparse` and `pgfplots`. How should I declare a pgf function with Lua correctly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{luasinh}{1}{%
    \begingroup
        \edef\pgfmath@arg{#1}%
        \directlua{tex.setdimen("pgfmath@x", math.sinh(\pgfmath@arg) .. "pt")}%
        \pgfmath@returnone\pgfmath@x%
    \endgroup
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent
Lua: \pgfmathsetmacro\luasinh{luasinh(1)}\luasinh\\
PGF: \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfsinh{sinh(1)}\pgfsinh\\

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot {sinh(x)};
        %\addplot {luasinh(x)}; does not work
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I think being able to use Lua in `LuaLaTeX` when declaring pgf functions could be useful. For example, this question ["Erf function in LaTeX"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107423/erf-function-in-latex) could maybe be answered without calling Gnuplot but simply call `math.erf` (if this exists?) in `\directlua`.

Comment: The problem is that `pgfplots` uses its own internal number format. Put `\typeout{#1}` into the `luasinh` definition and you will see stuff like `2Y4.5833334e0]` at the terminal. Lua has no idea what to do with that. If you can convert this internal format into a 'normal' number `\N` then you can just use `\edef\pgfmathresult{\directlua{tex.print("" .. math.sinh(\N))}}` followed by `\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup`.

Comment: Related question on the topic of FPU internal representation: [tikz pgf - pgfplots and calculations; without fpu 'dimension too large', with fpu 'Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)' - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/pgfplots-and-calculations-without-fpu-dimension-too-large-with-fpu-illegal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on @Mark Wibrow's comment, I have a working function declaration. The conversion from `pgfplots` internal syntax to something that is digestable by Lua feels wrong, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{luasinh}{1}{%
    \begingroup
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}%
        \pgfmathparse{#1}%
        \edef\pgfmathresult{\directlua{tex.print("" .. math.sinh(\pgfmathresult))}}%
        \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult%
    \endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand*\printtest[1]{%
    \section*{Test of $\sinh(#1)$}
    Lua: \directlua{tex.print("" .. math.sinh(#1))}~(directlua)\\
    Lua: \pgfmathsetmacro\luasinh{luasinh(#1)}\luasinh~(luasinh())\\
    Lua: \pgfmathparse{luasinh(#1)}\pgfmathresult~(pgfmathresult)\\
    %PGF: \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfsinh{sinh(#1)}\pgfsinh\\
}%

\begin{document}
\printtest{0}
\printtest{1}
\printtest{10}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-10:10]
        \addplot[mark=o] {sinh(x)};
        \addplot[mark=x] {luasinh(x)}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @ShreevatsaR and Martin Heller, How can I replicate this procedure to the erf function in LuaLatex?, thanks!