# pgfplot is constant zero

Tags: pgfplots

Currently I am trying to convert a plot I made with python and matplotlib to a pgfplot,
but the plot is constant zero. I checked the formula, it appears to be right,
so I dont have a clue why the plots differ. Here is the tex and the python code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{(20e-6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{((1/20)*1e-6)}

\begin{axis}[
    xmin=1,
    xmax=2e6,
    samples=5000,
    xlabel=$\omega$]

    \addplot[domain=2:2e6, black, thick] {1/(1 + ((x*\l)/\r - 1/(x*\r*\c))^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


def frac(a, b):
    return a / b

def h(w, r, l, c):
    return frac(1, 1 + (frac(w*l, r) - frac(1, w*r*c))**2)
```

I am glad for any help!

Comment: Please, next time post a compilable example like the one in my answer. And by the way, welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `\pgfmathsetmacro{}` is rounding the number and the range of numbers of `pgfmath` is quite limited (see note 2). I have added a debug node to show you that your `\l` (see note 1) is `0.0`...

I suggest using the `declare function` facility for this kind of thing (besides, the syntax is much better). There will be still limitations in the range of numbers, and the `dimension too large` error is very easy to have, but it's much more stable.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{(20e-6)}
    \tikzset{declare function={
            L=20e-6;
            R=4;
            C=(1/20)*1e-6;
        }
    }

    \node[red] at (3,3) {l is \l}; % just to debug

    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=1,
        xmax=2e6,
        samples=150,
        xlabel=$\omega$]

        \addplot[domain=2:2e6, black, thick] {1/(1 + (x*L/R - 1/(x*R*C))^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*note 1*: try not to use one-letter macros. It is very dangerous because a lot of them are defined for accents in the core LaTeX, and things can explode in unfathomable ways.

*note 2*:
The `pgfplots` manual says:

[image]
[image]

but be warned that using the [`fpu` manually can be tricky](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/pgfplots-and-calculations-without-fpu-dimension-too-large-with-fpu-illegal).

There are other mathematical engines around, like `xfp` for example, which are more "standard", but not so well integrated into the rest of `pgf`. For very complex calculations, is better to use external tools and then import the data points.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.
There is no way I would have figured that out by myselfe!